# Should I scale datetime variables?

Tags: python, data-science

I have a dataframe with different weather variables and datetime variables (month, day, hour). I'm going to use the variables to predict number of cyclist.
I want to scale the variables with StandardScaler, but should I include the datetime variables as well, or just scale the weather variables? It just feels wrong to scale the datetime variables.

Answer (score 0):

You should not scale `datetime` values cause its just the track of features and not `features` it self